# PowerShell: ConvertTo-Json problem containing special characters

Tags: json, powershell

I am writing a script to make changes to a JSON file but when the file is converted back to JSON it expands special characters.

For example the JSON File contain passwords with "&". A quick way to replicate the problem is using following command:

PS> "Password&123" | Convertto-Json
output is:"Password\u0026123"

```
##Here is how I import the JSON FILE:
$jsonfile = (Get-Content .\example.json -Encoding Ascii) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
##Exporting JSON FILE without modifying it.
$jsonfile  | ConvertTo-Json |Out-File "new.json"
```

--here is an example of simplified JSON FILE

```
{
    "Server1":
    {
        "username":"root",
        "password":"Password&dfdf"
    },
    "Server2":
    {
        "username":"admin",
        "password":"Password&1234"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by the automatic character escape feature of `Convertto-Json` and it affects several symbols such as `<>\'&`

ConvertFrom-Json will read the escaped characters properly. Using your example:

```
PS C:\> {"Password\u0026123"} | ConvertFrom-Json
Password&123
```

And your example code results in a file that has escaped characters, but `ConvertFrom-Json` can read it back to the original passwords. See below:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Content .\example.json -Encoding Ascii) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
Server1                                  Server2
-------                                  -------
@{username=root; password=Password&dfdf} @{username=admin; password=Password&1234}

PS C:\> (Get-Content .\new.json -Encoding Ascii) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json
Server1                                  Server2
-------                                  -------
@{username=root; password=Password&dfdf} @{username=admin; password=Password&1234}
```

If you need the passwords to be stored unescaped, some fancier work may be needed. See this thread about [Converting Unicode strings to escaped ascii strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615559/converting-unicode-strings-to-escaped-ascii-string)

Alternatively, avoid affected characters if possible.

Comment: Thanks! I think i am going to work on something to convert the password after its convertedfrom-json... Will update as soon i get something...

Comment: I just re-read your post and realize it's not a real problem anymore. Turn out to be a cosmetic issue for now. Even thought the password is in unicode, It works.. So I am not going to worry about converting it for now..

Answer (score 51):

Try the Unescape() method:

```
$jsonfile | ConvertTo-Json | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Out-File "new.json"
```

Comment: Warning: this removes ALL escapes, including some that might be needed in your JSON, e.g. escaped quote characters: `"expression": "My name is \"joe\""`. This leaves you with broken JSON...

Comment: I found the following answer to be most satisfying - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47779605/2778027