# Powershell not able to convert while converting values from "&" to JSON

Tags: json, powershell, csv

### RoleFullPath

```
Applications\User Admin & Support-DEMO
```

**PowerShell Code**

```
$NewJSON.roleFullPath = $Line.RoleFullPath
.
.
.
.
$JSONPath = $RolePath + $FolderName  + "-JSON.json"   
Convertto-JSON $NewJSON | Out-file -Encoding "UTF8" $JSONPath
```

### Output:

```
"roleFullPath":  "Applications\\User Admin \u0026 Support-DEMO"
```

While converting from csv to json, character '**&**' is getting converted to '**\u0026**'

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

In *Windows PowerShell* v5.1, `ConvertTo-Json` indeed unexpectedly encodes `&` characters as Unicode escape sequence `\u0026`, where `0026` represents hex. number `0x26`, the Unicode code point representing the [`&` character, `U+0026`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26/index.htm).
(PowerShell *Core*, by contrast, preserves the `&` as-is.)

That said, **JSON parsers should be able to interpret such escape sequences** and, indeed, the complementary `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet is.

- Note: The solutions below are *general* ones that can handle the Unicode escape sequences of *any* Unicode character; since **`ConvertTo-Json` seemingly only uses these Unicode escape-sequence representations for the characters `&`, `'`, `<` and `>`**, a **simpler solution** is possible, ***unless* false positives must be ruled out** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69351530/45375).

That said, **if you do want to *manually* convert Unicode escape sequences** into their character equivalents in JSON text, you can use the following - **limited solution**:

```sh
# Sample JSON with Unicode escapes.
$json = '{ "roleFullPath":  "Applications\\User Admin \u0026 Support-DEMO" }'

# Replace Unicode escapes with the chars. they represent,
# with limitations.
[regex]::replace($json, '\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}', { 
  param($match) [char] [int] ('0x' + $match.Value.Substring(2)) 
})
```

The above yields:

```sh
{ "roleFullPath": "Applications\\User Admin & Support-DEMO" }
```

Note how `\u0026` was converted to the char. it represents, `&`.

A **robust solution** requires more work:

- **There are characters that *must* be escaped in JSON** and cannot be represented literally, so in order **for the to-character conversion to work *generically*, these characters must be *excluded***.
- Additionally, *false positives* must be avoided; e.g., `\\u0026` is *not* a valid Unicode escape sequence, because a JSON parser interprets `\\` as an escaped `\` followed by verbatim `u0026`.
- Finally, the Unicode sequences for `"` and `\` must be translated into their *escaped* forms, `\"` and `\\`, and it is possible to represent a few ASCII-range control characters by C-style escape sequences, e.g., `\t` for a tab character (`\u0009`).

The following **robust solution** addresses all these issues:

```sh
# Sample JSON with Unicode escape sequences:
#  \u0026 is &, which CAN be converted to the literal char.
#  \u000a is a newline (LF) character, which CANNOT be converted, but can
#  be translated to escape sequence "\n"
# \\u0026 is *not* a Unicode escape sequence and must be preserved as-is.
$json = '{ 
  "roleFullPath": "Applications\u000aUser Admin \u0026 Support-DEMO-\\u0026" 
}'

[regex]::replace($json, '(?<=(?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})', {
  param($match)
  $codePoint = [int] ('0x' + $match.Groups[1].Value)
  if ($codePoint -in 0x22, 0x5c) { 
    # " or \ must be \-escaped.
    '\' + [char] $codePoint
  } 
  elseif ($codePoint -in 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xc, 0xd) { 
    # Control chars. that can be represented as short, C-style escape sequences.
    ('\b', '\t', '\n', $null, '\f', '\r')[$codePoint - 0x8]
  }
  elseif ($codePoint -le 0x1f -or [char]::IsSurrogate([char] $codePoint)) {
    # Other control chars. and halves of surrogate pairs must be retained
    # as escape sequences.
    # (Converting surrogate pairs to a single char. would require much more effort.)
    $match.Value
  }
  else {
    # Translate to literal char.
    [char] $codePoint
  }
})
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "roleFullPath": "Applications\nUser Admin & Support-DEMO-\\u0026" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop Powershell from doing this pipe your Json output through this

```bsh
$jsonOutput | ForEach-Object { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Set-Content $jsonPath -Encoding UTF8;
```

This will prevent the `&` being converted :)

Comment: While `[regex]::Unescape()` conveniently converts Unicode escape sequences into the actual characters they represent, applying this method to JSON text will _invalidate it_ as JSON, if it contains other instances of `\ ` characters, such as the `\\ `sequence in the question.