# & sign is converted into \u0026 through powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have below code:

```
$getvalue= 'true&amp;replicaSet=users-shard-0&amp;authSource=adsfsdfin&amp;readPreference=neasrest&amp;maxPoolSize=50&amp;minPoolSize=10&amp;maxIdleTimeMS=60'
$getvalue = $getvalue -replace '&amp;','&'
$pathToJson = 'C:\1\test.json'
$a = Get-content -Path $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.connectionStrings.serverstring=$getvalue
$a | ConvertTo-Json | Set-content $pathToJson -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I got below result:

```
true\u0026replicaSet=users-shard-0\u0026authSource=adsfsdfin\u0026readPreference=neasrest\u0026maxPoolSize=50\u0026minPoolSize=10\u0026maxIdleTimeMS=60
```

There **&** sign converted into \u0026. How to prevent covert value.
You can take reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644296/powershell-not-able-to-convert-while-converting-values-from-to-json)

I need **&** sign in json file instead of \u0026

Comment: ..but.. the [answer given to the question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644601/9898643) is not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Windows PowerShell*'s [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) unexpectedly serializes `&` to its equivalent *Unicode escape sequence* (`\u0026`)**; **ditto for `'`, `<` and `>`** (fortunately, this no longer happens in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*) - while unexpected and hindering readability - this **isn't a problem for *programmatic* processing**, since JSON parsers, including [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) do recognize such escape sequences:

```
($json = 'a & b' | ConvertTo-Json) # -> `"a \u0026 b"` (WinPS)
ConvertFrom-Json $json # -> verbatim `a & b`, i.e. successful roundtrip
```

**If you do want to convert such escape sequences to the verbatim character they represent**:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644601/45375) to the linked question shows a **robust, general string-substitution approach**.
- However, **in your case**  - given that you know the specific and only Unicode sequence to replace and there seems to be no risk of false positives - you can **simply use *another* [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation**:

```
$getvalue= 'true&amp;replicaSet=users-shard-0&amp;authSource=adsfsdfin&amp;readPreference=neasrest&amp;maxPoolSize=50&amp;minPoolSize=10&amp;maxIdleTimeMS=60'
$getvalue = $getvalue -replace '&amp;','&'

# Simulate reading an object from a JSON
# and update one of its properties with the string of interest.
$a = [pscustomobject] @{
  connectionStrings = [pscustomobject] @{
    serverstring = $getValue
  }
} 

# Convert the object back to JSON and translate '\\u0026' into '&'.
# ... | Set-Content omitted for brevity.
($a | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '\\u0026', '&'
```

Output (note how the `\u0026` instance were replaced with `&`):

```
{
  "connectionStrings": {
    "serverstring": "true&replicaSet=users-shard-0&authSource=adsfsdfin&readPreference=neasrest&maxPoolSize=50&minPoolSize=10&maxIdleTimeMS=60"
  }
}
```

---

You can cover *all* problematic characters - `&` `'`, `<` and `>` - with *multiple* `-replace` operations:

- However, if you need to rule out *false positives* (e.g., `\\u0026`), the more sophisticated solution from the [aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644601/45375) is required.

```
# Note: Use only if false positives aren't a concern.

# Sample input string that serializes to:
#   "I\u0027m \u003cfine\u003e \u0026 dandy."
($json = "I'm <fine> & dandy." | ConvertTo-Json)

# Transform the Unicode escape sequences for chars. & ' < >
# back into those chars.
$json -replace '\\u0026', '&' -replace '\\u0027', "'" -replace '\\u003c', '<' -replace '\\u003e', '>'
```