# Powershell - Add "Data" block when convertTo-JSON

Tags: powershell

How to add `"data" : [` block when using `$var | convertTo-Json`?

The actual output of `$var` is just a object with some properties which is then converted to json using the command `convertTo-Json`.

Here is what I get:

```
[
    {
        "controllerID":  "0",
        "DiskID":  "0:1:0",
        "cName":  "PERCS130",

    },
    {
        "controllerID":  "0",
        "DiskID":  "0:1:1",
        "cName":  "PERCS130",
    }
]
```

But I need something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "controllerID":  "0",
            "DiskID":  "0:1:0",
            "cName":  "PERCS130",

        },
        {
            "controllerID":  "0",
            "DiskID":  "0:1:1",
            "cName":  "PERCS130",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you show is invalid because of the comma's after `"cName":  "PERCS130"`. This is probably because you have stripped stuff out here.

What you need to do is create a new json, where a new element `data` contains the current json as array:

```
$json = @"
[
    {
        "controllerID":  "0",
        "DiskID":  "0:1:0",
        "cName":  "PERCS130"
    },

    {
        "controllerID":  "0",
        "DiskID":  "0:1:1",
        "cName":  "PERCS130"
    }
]
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$newjson = @{'data' = @($json)}
$newjson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3  # you may need to up the Depth value
```

Result:

```
{
    "data":  [
                 {
                     "controllerID":  "0",
                     "DiskID":  "0:1:0",
                     "cName":  "PERCS130"
                 },
                 {
                     "controllerID":  "0",
                     "DiskID":  "0:1:1",
                     "cName":  "PERCS130"
                 }
             ]
}
```

<sup>PowerShell does not produce 'pretty' json. If you need to convert it to properly spaced json, see my function [Format-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/9898643)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to make a new object with a data array property containing $var:

```
$newvar = [pscustomobject]@{data = $var}
$newvar

data
----
{@{controllerID=0; DiskID=0:1:0; cName=PERCS130}, @{controllerID=0; DiskID=0:1:1; cName=PERCS130}}
```

Then you can do convertto-json:

```
$newvar | convertto-json

{
  "data": [
    {
      "controllerID": "0",
      "DiskID": "0:1:0",
      "cName": "PERCS130"
    },
    {
      "controllerID": "0",
      "DiskID": "0:1:1",
      "cName": "PERCS130"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or with the json in a file and if you have jq.  Same output.

```
get-content file.json | jq '{data:.}'
```