# Convert a txt file to json file with powershell

Tags: json, powershell, timestamp, converters, txt

I have a txt file:

```
orange : 1
blue : 2
yellow : 3
```

And i want to convert this file to json which look like that :

```
{ "colors-20220906" : {
     "orange" : 1,
     "blue" : 2,
     "yellow" : 3
  }
}
```

Add a key with a timestamp.
Could you help me please, i'm blocked.
Thank you

Comment: The expected result isn't valid [Json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) either, it requires comma's between the color properties

Comment: PowerShell 7: `@{ 'colors-20220906' = (Get-Content .\Your.txt |ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter ':') } |ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot comma's.

Comment: { "colors-20220906" : {
     "orange" : 1,
     "blue" : 2,
     "yellow" : 3
  }
}

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73617484/edit) and correct the information in there (rather than putting it in a difficult to read comment).

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell 5 the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet does not have a `Delimiter` parameter and always uses the equals sign (`=`) as separator between the name and value of the input.

Also, `ConvertFrom-StringData` always returns a Hashtable, which is unordered by default.

```
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'TheFile.txt' -Raw
[PsCustomObject]@{'colors-20220906' = ($txt -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData )} | ConvertTo-Json
```

results in

```
{
    "colors-20220906":  {
                            "blue":  "2",
                            "yellow":  "3",
                            "orange":  "1"
                        }
}
```

If the order of subitems **is** important to you, you need to split the key:value lines yourself:

```
$txt  = Get-Content -Path 'TheFile.txt'
# create an ordered Hash to retain the order in which the items appear
$hash = [ordered]@{}  
foreach ($line in $txt) {
    $name,$value = ($line -split ':', 2).Trim()
    $hash[$name] = $value
}

[PsCustomObject]@{'colors-20220906' = $hash} | ConvertTo-Json
```

results in

```
{
    "colors-20220906":  {
                            "orange":  "1",
                            "blue":  "2",
                            "yellow":  "3"
                        }
}
```

P.S. PowerShell creates valid JSON, but the format is quite ugly. If you want to prettify that, you can use the function I posted earlier [Format-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/9898643)